# How to delete a branch using Bitbucket REST API

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

Using **postman**, I have succeeded in creating branches in bitbucket via their REST API and using the guide below

[Bitbucket Rest API Guide](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.5.0/bitbucket-branch-rest.html#idm138909639685792)

But I cannot delete a branch using the same guide as well.

I have created a JSON and placed it in the **body** tab of POSTMAN then using **DELETE** for the HTTP method but no success.

I am getting error **405 - Method Not Allowed**, what does that mean? Did my request pushed through but I am not allowed?

Using the bitbucket web UI, I am able to delete and create branches.

Edit:

This is the postman generated CURL

```
curl -X DELETE https://<url>/rest/api/1.0/projects/<abc>/repos/<xyz>/branches 
-H 'authorization: Bearer xxxxxx' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' 
-H 'content-type: application/json'  
-H 'x-atlassian-token: nocheck' 
-d '{"name": "refs/heads/feature/name","dryRun": false}'
```

Comment: You should read the docs to understand the error: _”The request HTTP method is not appropriate for the targeted resource. For example an HTTP GET to a resource that only accepts an HTTP POST will result in a 405.”_

Comment: You've linked to the Bitbucket Server API, which indicates that DELETE is a valid method. Are you trying to use that against Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org)?

Comment: I am using it for bitbucket server

Comment: Can you give examples of the exact URL you're trying to issue a DELETE against? It would be even better if you could provide a `curl` example to reproduce the issue

Comment: as Dave says -- what exactly is the URL you are hitting? The body should be irrelevant, I think.

Comment: i have updated the post with the CURL script that was generated by POSTMAN

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you're using the incorrect REST endpoint, one that doesn't accept the `DELETE` HTTP verb. The one you're using is:

```
/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/branches
```

As per [the docs](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.10.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idm46340514215280), this endpoint only accepts `GET`s and `POST`s

Judging by the format of your call, I'm guessing the one you're actually after is this:

```
/rest/branch-utils/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/branches
```

The [branch-utils API docs](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.8.0/bitbucket-branch-rest.html#idm45555984542992) describe more or less the exact payload you're trying to use.

Digging a little deeper and I believe this mistake isn't your fault. The Bitbucket branch util docs for Bitbucket 5.8 and below show the correct URL path, but for 5.9 and up [the path seems to be missing](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.9.0/bitbucket-branch-rest.html#idm45740952712016).

Full disclosure: I work for Atlassian. That being the case I'll chase this up and have it corrected :)

Edit: the docs have since been fixed!

Comment: oh my gosh! you are correct! thank you for pointing that out! and yes it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer gives the BB 1.0 API request details.  In the 2.0 API this is really simple.  It's just an empty delete request with no payload to:

`DELETE {{BB_API}}/repositories/{workspace}/{reposlug}/refs/branches/{branchname}`

So for example if you have repo "myrepo" in project "sandbox", to delete the branch named "test1" you'd do (excluding auth)

```
curl --location --request DELETE 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/sandbox/myrepo/refs/branches/test1'
```